# In Electron app how do you reference the temp path?

Tags: node.js, electron, temporary-files, tmp

Learning Electron I'd like to do some file processing after a [drag and drop](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop). On a Mac the equivalent for tmp is a `$TMPDIR`. Referencing the API documentation of [`app`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#app) I was able to locate the [`app.getAppPath()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetapppath) which shows my path from a simple console log from main.js. Below `app.getAppPath()` there is [`getPath()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname) but when I try `app.getPath(temp)`:

```
let foobar = app.getAppPath("temp")
console.log(foobar)
```

I get an error in the console of:

> ReferenceError: temp is not defined

Through my research I've read:

- [How to store user data in Electron](https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/how-to-store-user-data-in-electron-3ba6bf66bc1e)
- [How to get the original path of a portable Electron app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307797/how-to-get-the-original-path-of-a-portable-electron-app)
- [Creating and Using Temporary Files](https://discuss.atom.io/t/creating-and-using-temporary-files/27073)
- [Get Special folder Path in Electron](https://discuss.atom.io/t/get-special-folder-path-in-electron/30198/3)
- [electron temp directory](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=electron%20temp%20directory)
- [How to set a custom path for Electron app installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661129/how-to-set-a-custom-path-for-electron-app-installer)

In Electron is there a built-in for the temp directory to work on all operating systems or a `process` to reference?

### Note:

Even after referencing the string of:

```
console.log(`The temp path is: ${app.getAppPath("temp")}`)
```

it returns the same response as:

```
console.log(`The AppPath is: ${app.getAppPath()}`)
```

which is:

```
The temp path is: /Users/Grim/Documents/GitHub/electron-quick-start-boilerplate
The AppPath is: /Users/Grim/Documents/GitHub/electron-quick-start-boilerplate
```

and the above `console.log` tests have been added after `letWindow`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`app.getAppPath()` doesn't take an argument.

For `app.getPath(name)`, the argument should be the *string* `"temp"`: `app.getPath("temp")`.

Comment: So why does `console.log(\`The temp path is: ${app.getAppPath("temp")}\`)` return the same information as `app.getAppPath()` when added to main.js?

Comment: I guess that `getAppPath` doesn't use any arguments you might provide to it, since its documentation says it takes no arguments. `getAppPath()` would return the same as `getAppPath('temp')`, same as `getAppPath({something: 'useless'})`, same as `getAppPath(thisVariableCanHoldAnything)`.

Comment: I'm a little confused then by the documentation of `You can request the following paths by the name` I was expecting the same behavior as `$TMPDIR` or `$USER`

Comment: The method you need is `getPath`, _not_ `getAppPath`. Then you pass it the name you want, in your case it's `"temp"` (as a _string_): `console.log("tmp path is:", app.getPath("temp"))`

Comment: ah crap, you're right. Shouldnt code before coffee. +1 and accepted. I see what I was doing wrong now.

Comment: Good morning and happy coffee, then! ;)

Comment: Side note: when distributing your app, files will be put in an asar archive by default.  This will make them inaccessible to shell scripts that take a file path, for instance `wkhtmltopdf`.